# Matlab alternative to try/catch or continue after catch?

Tags: matlab, exception, try-catch, execution

im trying to set 70+ tiff tags to an image file that may or may not exist, If i try to set a tag and it throws an exception because the tag doesnt exist in this img file, i want to continue to try to set the remaining tags and i dont want to have 70 try/catch statements in sequence.

Any way to have it continue execution immidiately where it left off?

Ex:
not

```
try
     %matlab code to set tag1
catch ME
     %do nothing
end
try
     %matlab code to set tag2
catch ME
     %do nothing
end
try
     %matlab code to set tag3
catch ME
     %do nothing
end
```

but instead this:

```
try
     %Matlab code to set tag1, continue regardless of exception
     %Matlab code to set tag2 continue regardless of exception
     %Matlab code to set tag3, continue regardless of exception
catch ME
    %do nothing skip this tag and execute next line up there ^^^
end
```

Comment: I don't understand the premise: if you set the tag, it will be set, no? It doesn't need to exist prior to being set. And you know ahead of time which tags are legal.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `try` `catch` in a `while` loop:

```
count = 0;
err_count = 0;

while count == err_count

    try
        % my attmept to understand the tags you asked about
        if  your_tag_number(count) ~= the_tag_you_want;
            error
        end

    catch ME
        err_count = err_count + 1;
    end

    count = count + 1;
end
```